# IE not supporting as3 preloader action

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4, flash-cs5

I have used the below code.

```
stop();
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onLoadingAction);
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadedAction);
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErroAction);
function onLoadingAction (e:ProgressEvent):void 
{
    trace("loading");   
}
function onLoadedAction (e:Event):void 
{
    this.loaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onLoadingAction);
    gotoAndStop(currentFrame+1);
}
function ioErroAction (e:IOError):void 
{
    trace("Dev Ben " + e.toString());
}
```

This code is supporting for chrome and firefox. But if I run using IE, its stuck with onLoadingAction.

What do I needs to do to run in IE?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you get to output the traces of `onLoadingAction`?

Comment: @ goliatone: Read my question completely.

Comment: I did read it. I just don't understand what you mean by _stuck with onLoadingAction_ I had a similar issue in IE.

Comment: Stuck means... Its not moving to COMPLETE event handler, staying with progressEvent event handler.

Comment: Check with Mike Welsh answer... thats working well.

Comment: Actually, my issue was the other way around. I did not get the progress events...

Comment: Is in flash too?... Can u able to update the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the COMPLETE event of the root loaderInfo isn't reliable and behaves differently in different browsers. It will fail to fire in some browsers if the file is cached or running locally.

Instead, checked that loaderInfo.bytesLoaded == loaderInfo.bytesTotal in an ENTER_FRAME or TIMER handler:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{
    if(loaderInfo && loaderInfo.bytesLoaded == loaderInfo.bytesTotal)
    {
        // load complete
    }
}
```

Comment: could not the Progress event be used to make that check?

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe the ProgressEvent can have the same issues of not firing in certain environments. Just now when testing a local SWF in IE9, the PROGRESS event did not fire even though the COMPLETE event did. So, in general, I would not trust the events on the root loaderInfo, and would just check for the completion in an ENTER_FRAME.

Comment: Just ran into this problem with Flash 11.8 on IE10. Progress events won't fire when opening the file on local harddrive (c:/index.html loading c:/movie.swf). Switching to onEnterFrame and checking for bytesLoaded worked flawlessly. Thanks!